# What do these regular expressions match?

Tags: regex

I'm a complete novice when it comes to regular expressions.  I have come across some in a piece of code I am maintaining.  Could anyone help by letting me know what they do:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
^[\.$/0-9a-zA-Z_ -]+$
^[\.$/0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
```

All help appreciated thanks

Comment: Hint: `[]` denotes a character class.

Comment: You can read about that in in a good regex tutorial.

Comment: [There're many tutorials around the Internet](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=regular+expression+tutorial) that you can check out...

Comment: go to [regex101](http://regex101.com) and input the regex and get a nice print out of what it'll do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"^"   =   Matches the position before the first character in the string.

[0-9a-zA-Z_-]  or it could be "\w"
Matches any word character including underscore.

"+" =
matches when the preceding character occurs 1 or more times

"$"
matches the position after the last character in the string.

Comment: note: `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]`  would have to be `[\w-]`